# move turtle to closest turtle NETLOGO

Tags: netlogo

```
if any? livestock in-radius smell [
  set heading towards one-of livestock in-radius smell
]    

let predation one-of livestock-here in-radius smell    
if predation != nobody [
  ask predation [ 
    die 
  ]
  set energy energy + 11400 
]
```

This is my code for a predator moving towards prey. When he reaches an area with high density of turtles he cannot make a choice between the two and dies in the middle.

I have tried many different code formats including `min-one-of`and various other suggestions I found online but none have helped

Can anyone solve this problem.

Comment: I think you have an unnecessary `livestock-here` in your `let ...` chunk- it should just be `livestock`.

Comment: @LukeC, that should be probably be an answer instead of a comment, so that the answer could be accepted and the question closed... :-)

Comment: @NicolasPayette Done, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think you have an unnecessary livestock-here in your `let ...` chunk- try:

`let predation one-of livestock in-radius smell`

Otherwise, your predator will be trying to assess a `livestock` from the patch the predator is currently on.